# Designing an event based trigger based on a field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, redis, amazon-dynamodb

Currently I am working on a system which runs a cron job every few hours to trigger an API call. This call runs a SQL query to get all the active receipts that are due end of today or past due. The query joins 3 tables and takes a toll on the DB as it takes >30 seconds to finish or even times out. I am not really a fan of this because of reliability issues and want to redesign it.

The query is as follows (I am masking other details from the query but I get a few other columns etc..)-

```
SELECT r.id, s.statementId, r.customerId
FROM receipt r 
INNER JOIN statement s ON r.statementId = s.Id
LEFT JOIN customer c ON c.Id = r.customerId
WHERE c.location = 'US'
AND s.status = 'Active'
AND s.dueDate <= UTC_TIMESTAMP AND s.Canceled IS NULL
```

Initially I was thinking of using Redis on top of it and setting the due date as the expiration date. So whenever, a key expires, I could just listen to keyspace events and process data accordingly. However, this approach is half baked cuz first it's cache, so not really reliable. Second, I will have to do retry logic on failed processes etc..

Previously, in a similar problem I used DynamoDB's streams to listen to data that was getting expired at the ttl.

I am not a pro at MySQL by any means so throwing it out there to see if you guys have any ideas on how to work around this? Any suggestions on the design?

Comment: `WHERE c.location = 'US'` converts `LEFT JOIN customer` to INNER JOIN - replace.

Comment: Does your problem is long query execution? if so then provide complete CREATE TABLE for all used tables, complete query text and its execution plan, and some data statistic (total and matched rows amount).